# How do I count how many of a specific letter is in a sentence in python?

Tags: python-3.7

I am doing homework and need to count the amount of times the letter a appears in the sentence: The cat sat on the mat

I have only been using python for a year and can count the number of letters in that sentence, but that's as far as my expertise goes.

```
sentence = "The cat sat on the mat"
a = len()
print(a)
```

I can't work out what needs to be added or changed within the variable a

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's `string.count()` function, as in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

> string.count(s, sub[, start[, end]])
>   Return the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of substring sub in string s[start:end]. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values are the same as for slices.

```
sentence = 'The cat sat on the mat' 
sentence.count('a')
```